# yum groupremove 'Development Tools': keep packages required by other packages

Tags: rhel, yum

I did: `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
Now I want to remove it: `yum groupremove 'Development Tools'`

But it marks for deletion many other packages that require `binutils`.

How to keep `binutils`?

My native distro is `Arch`. There how yum removes packages by default is called `cascade`.

I could use `rpm` command directly, but the problem becomes opposite: it won't remove any package, if just one fails deps check:

```
# rpm -e apr binutils
error: Failed dependencies:
        binutils is needed by (installed) crash-5.0.0-23.el6.x86_64
        binutils is needed by (installed) module-init-tools-3.9-17.el6.x86_64
        binutils is needed by (installed) oprofile-0.9.6-7.el6.x86_64
        /usr/bin/ar is needed by (installed) redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.el6.x86_64
        /usr/bin/strip is needed by (installed) redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For groupremove it would be: `yum --setopt=groupremove_leaf_only=1 groupremove 'Development Tools'`

There's also a patch adding a similar `remove_leaf_only` option, that modifies `remove`, but  `yum` in `RHEL` 6.5 does not yet support it.

Comment: You can use --setopt to pass random config. options on the command line.